# Perform raw SQL with Entity Framework that doesn't get executed until SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework I'm making a bunch of data changes in a loop and calling `SaveChanges()` at the end, but one of the tables has a data type that Entity Framework doesn't support so I use a raw update statement. This makes two things happen: one, using `ExecuteSqlCommand()` causes the sql to be executed immediately, surrounded by `exec sp_reset_connection`, which greatly affects performance, and two, it's not part of the large transaction created by `SaveChanges()`, so if there's a problem it's not simply rolled back.

The transaction problem I believe can be solved by giving `ExecuteSqlCommand()` an outside transaction, but there's still a significant performance hit. Interestingly, I had the best performance by taking all of the generated sql strings, combining them into one big sql statement with a StringBuilder, then calling `ExecuteSqlCommand()` once right before `SaveChanges()`. This solution does not easily let me parameterize queries though, and would result in a huge, weird looking query with a massive array of objects representing all of the values.

So is there a built in way (or even a way at all) for me to include some SQL to be included with `SaveChanges`? I looked into doing it with an extension method, but it doesn't even look like there's a way to disable performing `exec sp_reset_connection` when `ExecuteSqlCommand()` is called in Entity Framework 6.

Comment: You're looking for `TransactionScope`.